# AdMob: is Test Device Id included in AdRequest?

Tags: android, admob

I use this code to build an AdRequest:

```
AdRequest request = AdRequest.Builder().
addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).
addTestDevice(id1).
addTestDevice(id2).
build();
```

Are those device Id's transmitted to ad server every time an ad request is executed?
(Or are they only used locally in order to decide whether live ads or test ads are requested?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only used locally. You will see test ads only when you add test device, if you remove the code of adding test device before calling build() the ad will load normal.

Admob first generates your device id before loading ad, and if your device id is listed in test devices then test ad is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide a link to the documentation on this subject?

Comment: @Pawel Hello, actually this is quite a small topic and is not much widely documented, i have been using admob from quite sometime so i know it from my invetigation in the admob library code( i also wanted to know when i add the test device once, then will it not recieve normal ads ) so i looked into the library code and it made it clear, that it only checks for the test device before loading ad in the AdRequestParcel constructor
the function used is named isTestDevice(Context context) and it checks for if the current device id is contained in the set of added test device.